# Cannot find module cv2 even if it's installed

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I encountered a problem where I have installed opencv in my anaconda environment using this command:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

But for some reason when I enter into my environment using python and error occurs stating: 'No module named cv2', has someone encountered a similar problem, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use `cv2`, you need to install `opencv-python`, not the contrib. You can do it by `pip install opencv-python`.